# Multiple plugins with the same name in Unity 2018.2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project built with earlier version of Unity. If I open it shows bunch of errors in console related to plugins name duplication. I tried to delete many times  but they keeps reappearing.

Heres a errors:

```
Multiple plugins with the same name 'vcomp120' (found at 'Packages/com.unity.textmeshpro/Plugins/vcomp120.dll' and 'Assets/TextMesh Pro/Plugins/vcomp120.dll'). That means one or more plugins are set to be compatible with Editor. Only one plugin at the time can be used by
```

And

```
C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Unity/cache/packages/packages.unity.com/com.unity.textmeshpro@1.2.4/Scripts/Runtime/TMP_Text.cs(4896,40): error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: `TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Multiply(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)' and `TMPro.TMPro_ExtensionMethods.Multiply(this UnityEngine.Color32, UnityEngine.Color32)'
```

[image]

I failed to solve this and couldn't find a solution. How can solve this? How to remove Packages folder/ disable / solve confliction with multiple same package files that I dont intent to import double times?

Answer (score 3):

Later versions of Unity use the [Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.package-manager-ui@1.8/manual/index.html) which is a window where you can manage packages in your project. These packages are not put into your Assets folder but instead are put in a separate Packages folder:

[image: Packages folder in the project window.]

TextMesh Pro is one of the default packages which Unity adds so you'll either need to remove the existing TextMesh Pro you manually added into your project from **Assets/TextMesh Pro/**

*OR*

You can remove the package via the package manager by opening it from **Window > Package Manager** then selecting TextMesh Pro and pressing the remove button on the top right of the window.

[image]

---

The benefits of using the Package Manager means it's easier to update extensions in your project, as they're outside of the Asset folder it obviously also reduces the amount of files in there keeping things a bit cleaner.

Comment: Nice answer. If manually removed then the project breaks and it doesn't automatically access TMpro objects from that folder.